# Awesome WM create shortcuts with 2 keys

Tags: awesome

With Awesome WM > 4.0, I would like to have a key shortcut with two keys.

I know I could have several modifiers with the first arg of `awful.key({}, "k", ...)`, but I would like to do it with several "classic" keys : `XF86Display` and Left-key for example, (in fact, any combination of a XF86 key and an arrow key).
Unfortunately, `awful.key({}, {"XF86Display", "Left"}, fun..)` doesn't work as the 2nd arg should be a string, not a table.

Do you know any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documnetation](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.key.html) it is not possible. The modifier key must be one of Any, Mod1, Mod2, Mod3, Mod4, Mod5, Shift, Lock and Control and as you already pointed out the key argument can only be a single string were you specify a single key.

Comment: You're right, it seems not possible.

I managed to do what I wanted using a keygrabber: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/keygrabber.html